# Error starting application 0xc000007b with include boost asio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, boost-asio

the same version of the library tested in a normal project, works. But when moved code to a project С++ CLI WinForms when starting application showing messangebox error 0xc000007b.
At the same time, other libraries from boost are successfully connected and working in the same project (its serialization and python).

What could be the problem?

Form1.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
//asio
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
//
//#include <Python.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
// include headers that implement a archive in simple text format
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
// включаем, чтобы сериализация работала с векторами
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
// включаем, чтобы нормально проходила сериализация XML
#include <boost/serialization/nvp.hpp>
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h> // setenv
#include <stdio.h>
//using extern "C"
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <locale>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
//
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h> //Shlwapi.lib в настр. проекта также 
#include <cassert>
#include "leveldb/db.h"
```

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg7UE.png)

Comment: Are you using 32 bit/64 bit? Did you use the Fusion Log? Did you use http://www.dependencywalker.com?

Comment: 32 bit. Fusion Log just tried it, recording is enabled in settings, but the log is empty and nothing appears( Dependency Walker looked but nothing unusual not observed.

Comment: Here my project source and exe https://yadi.sk/d/N3JcxPzd3Vpudf